# Basics Pointers c++

Tags: c++, pointers

[Pointer Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b7T1.png)

```
// more pointers
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int firstvalue = 5, secondvalue = 15;
  int * p1, * p2;

  p1 = &firstvalue;  // p1 = address of firstvalue
  p2 = &secondvalue; // p2 = address of secondvalue
  *p1 = 10;          // value pointed to by p1 = 10
 Line 14 - *p2 = *p1;         // value pointed to by p2 = value pointed to by p1
  p1 = p2;           // p1 = p2 (value of pointer is copied)
  *p1 = 20;          // value pointed to by p1 = 20

  cout << "firstvalue is " << firstvalue << '\n';
  cout << "secondvalue is " << secondvalue << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

I feel like I understand everything except when I get to line 14.
My question is the pointer p1 now equal to the address space that p2 is pointing too ? Also how did firstvalue = 10 and secondvalue= 20?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to include your code.

Comment: What does your textbook tell you? Also, code goes *in* the question, *not* behind an external link.

Comment: It's on the "pointer example" blue link it's a picture.

Comment: Include your code as text, not an image

Comment: @Alex Yet you ignored what was said. Please [edit] the question, to Include [mcve], as text, not as an image.

Comment: My bad I'm new to posting.

Comment: @Alex 1) You should've read through [ask], and [help], before asking if you are new. 2) All of the comments explain it pretty well, in my opinion. What is unclear about them?

Comment: The comment in the code on line 14 tells you what it does. And the comments on the lines before and after line 14 tell you what they're doing as well. Everything that you've asked about here is explained in those comments. How can we explain it any more clearly by repeating the same thing those comments say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my line-by-line explanation:

We start out with `p1` pointing to `firstvalue`, and `p2` pointing to `secondvalue`. `firstvalue` is 5, and `secondvalue` is 10.

```
*p1 = 10;
```

`firstvalue` is now 10.

```
*p2 = *p1;
```

Takes the thing pointed to by `p1` (`firstvalue`, with a value of 10) and assigns it to the thing `p2` points to (`secondvalue`). `firstvalue` and `secondvalue` are now both 10.

```
p1 = p2;
```

Assigns `p2` to `p1`. `p1` and `p2` now both point to `secondvalue`.

```
*p1 = 20;
```

Sets the thing `p1` points to (`secondvalue`) to 20. `firstvalue` is 10 and `secondvalue` is 20 now.